# remove() function is working rudely with animate css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am working with a piece of code that is fixed positioned but the problem is when it's on close, it doesn't animate . The code also uses `remove()`. But, if I only use animate css it works smooth.

### Code block

```
$(".full-screen-search").addClass('animated zoomOut').delay(1000).remove();
```

Is there a problem with this code? I can't tell.

### The full function is

```
function searchClose(){
   $(".full-screen-search").addClass('animated zoomOut').delay(1000).remove();
};
```

I have added delayed function so that it is removed after 1 second after the class has been added.

Comment: `.remove()` is not a queue-able method.

Comment: so what can i do to make it smooth?

Comment: can you create a fiddle too

Answer (score 0):

You can't use .remove() chained with other methods.  Try separating them with setTimeout instead:

```js
$(".full-screen-search").addClass('animated zoomOut');
setTimeout(function($(".full-screen-search").remove();), 1000)
```

Comment: or he can also use .one ... I think it was suggested by animate.css! https://github.com/daneden/animate.css (use .one to check when the animation on that element ended and, inside the callback, call .remove())

Answer (score -1):

If you use a javascript callback, it will wait on the function to complete before running said callback. Here is an example:

```
$(".full-screen-search").hide(1000, function() {
        $(".full-screen-search").remove();
});
```